# Tikz - Drawing fully connected neural network vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reproduce the following image but vertically and with 1 input neuron:
[image]
Is it possible to draw this vertically?

Comment: Do you have the code for the horizontally? Simply add a `rotate=90`.

Comment: @JouleV Wouldn't that rotate the text as well?

Comment: @Superuser27 Of course, we have to do something more with the nodes, but I think it will be too long for a comment. `rotate=90` is a _general_ hint, it is not an answer.

Comment: I don't have the original latex code.

Comment: This site has many examples. Just take one of them and then do as @JouleV suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*YouTube comment section:* One last video before bed.</sup>
<sup>*Me:* One last Ti*k*Z picture before bed.</sup>

---

Here is a good starting point

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cir/.style={circle,draw=#1,minimum size=0.5cm},y=0.6cm,font=\sffamily]
\begin{scope}[rotate=90]
\node[cir=blue!50!black] (a1) at (0,0) {};
\node[cir=blue!50!black] (a2) at (0,-1) {};
\node[cir=blue!50!black] (a3) at (0,-2) {};
\node[cir=blue!50!black] (a4) at (0,-4) {};
\node[cir=blue] (b1) at (2,0) {};
\node[cir=blue] (b2) at (2,-1) {};
\node[cir=blue] (b3) at (2,-2) {};
\node[cir=blue] (b4) at (2,-4) {};
\node[cir=blue] (c1) at (4,0) {};
\node[cir=blue] (c2) at (4,-1) {};
\node[cir=blue] (c3) at (4,-2) {};
\node[cir=blue] (c4) at (4,-4) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (d1) at (6,0) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (d2) at (6,-1) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (d3) at (6,-2) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (d4) at (6,-4) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (e1) at (8,0) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (e2) at (8,-1) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (e3) at (8,-2) {};
\node[cir=blue!50] (e4) at (8,-4) {};
\node[cir=green!50!black] (x) at (10,-2) {};
\foreach \i/\j in {a/b,c/d} {
    \foreach \cnto in {1,2,3,4} {
        \foreach \cntt in {1,2,3,4} {
            \draw[-latex] (\i\cnto.north)--(\j\cntt.south);
        }
    }
}
\foreach \i/\j in {b/c,d/e} {
    \foreach \cnt in {1,2,3,4} \draw[-latex] (\i\cnt)--(\j\cnt);
}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} \draw[-latex] (e\i.north)--(x.south);
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {a,b,c,d,e} {
    \draw ({2*(\j-1)},-3) node {$\cdots$};
}
\end{scope}
\draw (a1) node[blue!50!black,left=1em] {Input Variable Size};
\draw (b1) node[blue,left=1em] {Hidden 1 -- 128 Units};
\draw (c1) node[blue,left=1em] {Now I think you can do the rest};
\draw (d1) node[blue!50,left=1em] {Anyway, happy $\pi$ day!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you sleep well now...

Comment: I hope the sandman (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman) will bring you many upvotes :)